# My YouTube Watch Later list is empty even after adding Videos

Tags: youtube, youtube-watch-later

Here's what I've tried:

1. Click the little clockface to View it Later
2. Go to my View It Later in YouTube. List is empty.
3. I get a message: Your list is empty. Add videos to your list using this button: [+] but I don't see that button anywhere.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like it's just a bug.

If I look at all my lists (in a row across the top of you YouTube account) it shows View Later as being empty. If I click on the view list hyperlick below it though,I get the list with the recently added videos.

Comment: Better report it then.